# PIVOT SQL Server table to return columns / rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PHONES]
(
    [ITEM_SERIAL] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ATTRIBUTE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ATR_VALUE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ITEM_IMEI] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This table contain info about my phones such as IMEI,COLOR,MAKE,MODEL etc...
The key in this table is ITEM_SERIAL.

I want to return the results as columns per each phone.

I.E., instead of this:

[image: This]

I need to get query like this

```
select Make, Model, Model_Number, Memory, Carrier 
from phones
```

Comment: *If* you do EAV (Entity Attribute Value) then do it right: a table for the entity (here: phone), a table for the attribute (containing the distinct `ATTRIBUTE` data in your current table) and the value table referring to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three approaches -- multiple joins, pivot, and conditional aggregation.  I tend to go for the last:

```
select p.item_serial,
       max(case when attribute = 'MAKE' then atr_value end) as make,
       max(case when attribute = 'MODEL' then atr_value end) as model,
       . . .
from phones p
group by p.item_serial;
```

Why do I prefer this?  The performance is consistent, regardless of the number of attributes (in contrast to the `join` method).  The syntax combines basic SQL features and is more powerful than `pivot` (everything you can do with `pivot` you can do with conditional aggregation, and more).

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    [Make]          ,
    [Model]         ,
    [Model_Number]  ,
    [Memory]        ,
    [Carrier]
from
(
  select
    [ATTRIBUTE] ,
    [ATR_VALUE]
  from
    [dbo].[PHONES]
)
    result
pivot
(
  max([ATR_VALUE])
  for
    [ATTRIBUTE]
    in
    (
        [Make]          ,
        [Model]         ,
        [Model_Number]  ,
        [Memory]        ,
        [Carrier]
    )
)
    pivot_result
```

find PIVOT and UNPIVOT syntax in the following link:

[FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)